# Bash - change text copied to the clipboard using xclip

Tags: bash, xclip

I am trying to convert text copied to the clipboard from something like this:

```
+50.8863-114.0157/
```

to something like this:

```
geo:50.8927777778,-114.013055556,0
```

I found this code on the Web:

```
#!/bin/bash
x="geo:"$(xclip -o | tr -d ' ')
notify-send $x -i info
xclip -selection c
```

but it just removes the white space.
What I need to do is:
having `+xx.xxxx-yy.yyyy/` in clipboard
where `x` and `y` are numbers 0 - 9

- extract the text from the clipboard as an argument
- cut `+` from the beginning
- add `geo:` in the beginning
- add `xx.xxxx` after `geo:` (no spaces)
- add `,` after `xx.xxxx` (no spaces)
- add `yy.yyyy` after `,` (no spaces)
- cut `/` from the end
- add `,0` to the end (no spaces)
- return the result to the clipboard

---

ADDED LATER
I figured that out myself. Here is the code that worked:

```
clipboard_original="$(xclip -o)"
latitude=${clipboard_original:0:8}
longitude=${clipboard_original:8:9}
clipboard_for_digikam_geo=""geo:""${latitude//+}"00000,"${longitude//+}"00000"
echo "$clipboard_for_digikam_geo" | xclip -selection c
exit
```

Comment: What does "did not work" mean? What were you expecting, and what did you get?
Did you look at the man pages for `xclip` and `tr` (`man PROGRAM_NAME`)?
`xclip -o` outputs the contents of the clipboard, which is what you want here.
Piping (`|`) it to another program is appropriate here.
What do you think `tr -d ' '` does? A quick look at the man page shows that it deletes spaces from its input string. Not at all what you want.
`sed` would do what you want, or `awk`. WARNING: those are not simple tools (but oh so powerful).
`xclip -selection c` is also not doing anything useful...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This oneliner is basically what you need:

```
xclip -o | sed -rne's/\+?(-?[[:digit:].]+)\+?(-?[[:digit:].]+)\//geo:\1,\2,0/p' | xclip -i
```

Explanation:

- `xclip -o` outputs the X selection to the standard output
- `sed <regex>` parses the format you gave (ignoring leading `+`'es) and prints the replacement text

  - `-r` switch instructs the `sed` to interpret regular expressions as *Extended Regular Expressions* (ERE) (quick intro [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Regular_Expressions/POSIX-Extended_Regular_Expressions)),
  - `-n` suppresses the output of (unmatched/unwanted) input -- so we have to explicitly print with the `p` command (the last letter in sed script)
  - `-e script` defines the sed script:

    - `s/regexp/replacement/` will match `regexp` in each line of input (only the first occurrence) and replace it with `replacement` (which can include input groups, like `\1`). The `p` in the sed script actually prints the replacement text.
    - regexp (in short) is made up of two identical consecutive subpatterns: `<optional +>(<optional -><one or more digits/dot>)`. Parentheses define a group which we use in the replacement.
- `xclip -i` sets X selection from stdin (sed's output)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am having a hard time understanding sed's  syntax so I just used bash's internal tools. It is not a oneliner but it works and I can actually read it. :) I pasted the code to my initial post. Again, thank you for your help anyways!

Comment: @AndriusWild I've added explanation on `sed` invocation/script. If you prefer pure `bash` solution, check the `=~` regular expression matching operator within double brackets test expression (available since bash v3 -- so it works even on OS X :)), combined with `BASH_REMATCH` variable.